# Get currently logged in users with powershell to add shortcut to desktop

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a script that I deploy using LANDesk and in the script it calls a powershell script to add a shortcut to a network folder on the user's desktop.  LANDesk logs in to run the script with a local machine account but I don't want the shortcut to be put on that desktop but of the desktop of the user that is currently logged in. Is there a way to do this in powershell?

Here is my code for adding the shortcut if you run the script as the logged in user (can't run as the user themselves because they don't have admin rights)

```
$wshshell = new-object -comobject WScript.Shell
$Ink = $wshshell.CreateShortcut("$home\Desktop\PI_Users.lnk")
$Ink.TargetPath = "\\htntfs04\PI_Users"
$Ink.Save()
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using LANDesk, and you're using a package to distribute the script, you can choose between executing the script as *LocalSystem* which is the default, or as the *Current user's account*.

Just open the properties of the package, go to Accounts and choose *"Current user's account"*. The task will fail if there's no user logged in to the machine.

But, if I understand correctly, the problem is that the user is not allowed to create a link on its own desktop? If so, this solution won't work and the task would fail anyway!

Another approach I often use would be to execute a script that loops through all the local profiles and creates a link on the desktop of each user. If it's okay for you to use a WSH script instead of a powershell script, you could use something like this:

```
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002

Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")
Set ws = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList"
objRegistry.EnumKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, arrSubkeys

For Each objSubkey In arrSubkeys
  strValueName = "ProfileImagePath"
  strSubPath = strKeyPath & "\" & objSubkey
  objRegistry.GetExpandedStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strSubPath, strValueName, strProfile

  If Left(strProfile, Len(ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%windir%"))) <> ws.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%windir%") Then
    Set objShtCut = ws.CreateShortcut(strProfile & "\Desktop\PI_Users.lnk")
    objShtCut.TargetPath = "\\htntfs04\PI_Users"
    objShtCut.Save
    Set objShtCut = Nothing
  End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use `[Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")` to get the desktop's path for current user?

Comment: When LANDesk deploys the script it runs the script as a local admin account (not the end-user). Although the user is logged in, they aren't considered the "current user" so they $env would return the desktop of the admin account which the end-user can't access.